# How to refer to a specific textbox field in a specific record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a serch form and I want to be able to change value of text box field in a specific found record.

I have a combobox named Combo2 and a text box named TextBox1. I want to based on the selection in the combobox Combo2 change behaviour of the TextBox1. Problem that im suffering right now from is that selection of any record makes changes to all records not just the one I want.

Example: I look for a specific item and I get result that I have 5 items in Germany, 2 in England, 8 in Italy and 4 more in England. Now I want to move 2 items from England to Spain. When I select Spain in Combo box all TextBoxes in all records become inactive. I want only the textbox of record that I have changed to be inactiv.

```
Private Sub Combo2_AfterUpdate()
If Me.Combo2 = "England" Then
    Me.TextBox1.Enabled = True
    ElseIf Me.Combo2 = "Germany" Then
             Me.TextBox1.Value = "Ger"
             Me.TextBox1.Enabled = False
             ElseIf Me.Combo2 = "Spain" Then
                    Me.TextBox1.Value = "S"
                    Me.TextBox1.Enabled = False
                    ElseIf Me.Combo2 = "Italy" Then
                            Me.TextBox1.Value = "I"
                            Me.TextBox1.Enabled = False                                                                  
Else
    Me.TextBox1.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you post an image of your form highlighting Combo2 and TextBox1? If you don't have enough rep to put images directly in to your question, go to imgur.com and upload it there then put the hyperlink in your question.

Answer (score 0):

That is by design. A control in a continuous form will behave and react the same on all records except for the Value property (which is bound to the record).

So you will have to rethink your concept and how to navigate the form and records.

Comment: I was afraid of that ... Do You think it's possible to fool it by applying it only to the currently selected record ?

Comment: No, but you may be able to use the _header_ or the _footer_ of the form as controls here relate only to the current record.